# UIImageView “animation Movement ” How?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimageview

how  can show image same as following video in UIImageView ?

http://youtu.be/wfMksaMjA4w

i have a big image , i need to show some parts first and using animation to move slowly to other part of that image.

thanks

Comment: Use UISCrollview and set content offset based on your requirement.

Comment: you can also oversize your UIImageView and use `[UIView animateWithDuration: animations:]` the frame origin of your UIImageView